# ImageView: adjustViewBounds does not work with layout_height="fill_parent"?

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I'm trying to place in single row the `EditText` with the `ImageView` on the left. But I can't get the image to be scaled properly to match the height of text entry.

The layout is simple:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

(I highlighted image background by red color to see the actual space allocated by ImageView)

---

If I specify the exact height for `ImageView`:

```
            android:layout_height="48dp"
```

then I get the closest view  what I needed:
[image]

But I do not know the exact height of `EditText`, so I can't specify it for `ImageView` here.

---

When the height for `ImageView` is specified to fill its parent (to match ``EditText` height):

```
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

then I get unexpected extra margin between the image and text entry:
[image]

Actually, in this case the `ImageView` width equals to unscaled image width, whereas the image was scaled.

---

It's the similar to picture shown below if I specify `layout_height` to `48dp` and set `adjustViewBounds` to `false`:

```
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
```

[image]

---

So, the question here is: how to define the layout correctly to scale the image to match edit entry height and in the same time to have width of `ImageView` to be shrunk to scaled image width ? In other words how to get rid this extra space off?

Comment: try using android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" for imageview

Comment: @JSE How would it help? I will get smaller image but with the same extra space around.

Comment: Try using scaleType="fitXY" and height="fill_parent" for the ImageView.

Comment: @Karan Then I lose correct proportions of the image. Because, with the setting you proposed the image will be scale vertically only.

Answer (score 7):

This is a LinearLayout bug. If you look at `forceUniformHeight` in the source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#LinearLayout.forceUniformHeight%28int%2Cint%29). You can see that to handle sizing child views which supply `match_parent` as the height when the LinearLayout is set to `wrap_content`, the LinearLayout pretends to have an absolute height, recalculates the child height and then reuses the child width from the previous measure pass. Basically your image is calculating height and width unconstrained and getting default width and height, and then having height recalculated but being forced to use the old width. You will need to supply a height or override some View `onMeasures`

Answer (score 0):

you can also put gravity to be centered on the linear layout

NOTE: that you should also have different images in drawables-hdpi/ldpi and mdpi